# Questions about k elements subset of an n elements set.

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I need to prove by induction that

the number of 2-elements subset of an n elements set is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

I am stuck on where I should start from and how should I solve this.

I am guessing that I should begin with something like this:

${0 \choose 2} +{1 \choose 2}+{2 \choose 2} +...+{n \choose 2}$ = $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $

step 1.
let $n = 1$

${0 \choose 2} + {1 \choose 2} = \frac{1(1-1)}{2}$

$0 = 0$

True for $n = 1$

step 2. assume $n = k$

${0 \choose 2} +{1 \choose 2}+{2 \choose 2} +...+{k \choose 2}$ = $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$

step 3. let $n = k+1$

${0 \choose 2} +{1 \choose 2}+{2 \choose 2} +...+{k \choose 2} + {k+1 \choose 2}$ = $\frac{k+1(k+1 - 1)}{2}$

from step 2, ${0 \choose 2} +{1 \choose 2}+{2 \choose 2} +...+{k \choose 2}$ = $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$

so

$\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ + ${k+1 \choose 2}$ = $\frac{k+1(k+1 - 1)}{2}$

and I am not sure what I should do from here or whether I am on the right track.

can someone clear me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of binomial coefficients you are using is not correct. Try this instead.

If $n=0$ or $n=1$, then there are no 2-element subsets. Also, in both cases $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=0$.
Now assume that the statement is true for some $n\ge 1$, and consider a set $X$ of size $n+1$. Choose a fixed element $x$ of $X$. Then, by the induction hypothesis there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ 2-element subsets of $X$ that **do not** contain $x$. There are also $n$ 2-element subsets that contain $x$, by pairing $x$ with each other element of $X$. In total, that gives
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{2n}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$$
2-element subsets of $X$, as required.

Comment: I tired using binomial coefficient but I am even more confused.
When I use the binomial coefficient, I get  something like
$\frac{k(k-1)}{2} + \frac{(k+1)!}{2!(k+1-2)!} = \frac{k+1(k)}{2}$.
how should I carry on from here?
I can't evaluate any further with $\frac{(k+1)!}{2!(k+1-2)!}$ this part here :(